# Change status bar color Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my app, there is a dark mode, and I would like to know how to change the status bar color?
Thanks,

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

May be below lines of code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate.m` could help:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {

    statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//set whatever color you like
}
```

Comment: Don't do this, this is a hack and might get your app rejected for using private apis

Comment: Thank you very much! Only this works to black out the bar status. Just change statusBar.alpha

Answer (score 6):

Ok, according to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622923-setstatusbarstyle?language=objc) `setStatusBarStyle:animated:` is deprecated since iOS 9.0, and you should now put this code instead:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle 
{
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 5):

Add these lines in plist

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: This worked for me, this should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**A simple and effective way is to add a property to the `info.plist` and set the status bar style as `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.**

[This works like a charm](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-change-status-bar-color-ios-8-ahmed-ali/) !

**What we should do is:**

- First open the `info.plist` file of your app, then add a property `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` and set its value to `NO`
- Next head to your `Appdelegate` or any class file and use the following code:

  ```
  UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
  ```

  Another way to write the code is:

  ```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
  ```

Comment: 'setStatusBarStyle:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle 
{
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}. LOOK BELOW for the latest solution for Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 solution:
In view controller that needs non-default status bar appearance, use this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

click on navigationBar -> style -> Default
Then select Translucent and below that Bar Tint -> (select any colour you want)

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 13 came out, we have to resort to new properties in view of `status bar`, place following code under

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {

        UIView *statusBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame];

        if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {

            statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:statusBar];



    } else {
        UIView *statusBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame];

        if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {

            statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        }

    }
```

This takes care of the crash that takes place in iOS 13 and sets frame for other iOS versions too